# In VersionOne REST API how does one use multiple “with” statements with multiple “Where” clauses?

Tags: api, rest, where-clause, versionone

With the following query:

```
Base-URL/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic?sel=Category.Name,Custom_RoadmapInOut&where=Number=$numbers&with=$numbers=E-05322%2CE-05280%2CE-05616%2CE-04942%2CE-04921
```

I am getting the following response:

```
<Assets total="5" pageSize="2147483647" pageStart="0">
<Asset href="End-of-Base-URL/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic/138904" id="Epic:138904">
<Attribute name="Category.Name">Business Objective</Attribute>
<Attribute name="Custom_RoadmapInOut">2</Attribute>
</Asset>
<Asset href="End-of-Base-URL/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic/139078" id="Epic:139078">
<Attribute name="Category.Name">Initiative</Attribute>
<Attribute name="Custom_RoadmapInOut">1</Attribute>
</Asset>
<Asset href="End-of-Base-URL/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic/147147" id="Epic:147147">
<Attribute name="Category.Name">Parent Story</Attribute>
<Attribute name="Custom_RoadmapInOut"/>
</Asset>
<Asset href="End-of-Base-URL/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic/148702" id="Epic:148702">
<Attribute name="Category.Name">Parent Story</Attribute>
<Attribute name="Custom_RoadmapInOut"/>
</Asset>
<Asset href="End-of-Base-URL/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic/156961" id="Epic:156961">
<Attribute name="Category.Name">Milestone</Attribute>
<Attribute name="Custom_RoadmapInOut"/>
</Asset>
</Assets>
```

I want to limit the results to only return those assets that have a "Category.Name" of either "Business Objective" or "Initiative" and from those types to only return the ones that have a "Custom_RoadmapInOut" set to between 1 and 99.

What do I need to add to the query to have VersionOne do the heavy lifting and return only the desired items?

I am thinking I should be able to also add:
`Category.Names=$names&with=$names=Business+Objective%2CInitiative`
to the query and another where part to check the `Custom_RoadmapInOut` but I am not sure how to do this.

Currently I am making multiple queries and then using my own code to go through the results and keep only the ones that I desire to see.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Doug

Answer (score 3):

Multiple `with` values can be separated by `|` (pipe). If you need more details than are shown in the [documentation](http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Queries/with), you can try reading the [grammar](https://github.com/versionone/Grammars/blob/master/V1FilterContext.g).

Multiple `where` filter tokens must be joined by logical operators. Logical `and` is `;` (semicolon). Logical `or` is `|` (pipe). Again, the [documentation](http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Queries/where) can be a little sparse so you might try reading the [grammar](https://github.com/versionone/Grammars/blob/master/V1Query.g).

If you still find yourself still needing to run multiple queries to get what you need, you may find it advantageous to convert to the [query.v1](http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Tour_of_query.v1) endpoint.